# making the bot resend embeds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so the idea is for the bot to send an embed to a channel, then resend it with a new footer
this is the code i'm testing with:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  global test_channel, bot_command_channel, cu_free_games_channel
  test_channel = bot.get_channel(868816978293452841)
  bot_command_channel = bot.get_channel(808734570283139162)
  cu_free_games_channel = bot.get_channel(873018877020373043)

  print('bot is ready')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):


  if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    embed_old = discord.Embed(
      title= '''this is the title''', 
      description= '''this is the description''', 
      color= discord.Color.red(),
      # url= '''https://www.google.com/'''
      )
    embed_old.set_footer(text='old footer')
    await bot_command_channel.send(embed=embed_old)


  if message.channel == bot_command_channel:
    if not len(message.embeds):
      return
    else:
      embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()
      print(embed_content_in_dict) #prints out the embed's content

      for embed in embed_content_in_dict:
        embed_new = discord.Embed(
          title= embed_content_in_dict["title"],
          type= embed_content_in_dict["type"],
          description= embed_content_in_dict["description"],
          url = embed_content_in_dict["url"], # if the URL in embed_old is commented out, it throws an exception
          )
        embed_new.set_footer(text='new footer')
        await test_channel.send(embed=embed_new)
        return


  

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

this is what prints in the console:

```
bot is ready

{'footer': {'text': 'old footer'}, 'color': 15158332, 'type': 'rich', 'description': 'this is the description', 'title': 'this is the title'}

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 47, in on_message
    url = embed_content_in_dict["url"], # if the URL in embed_old is commented out, it throws an exception
KeyError: 'url'
```

so how can i detect if the embed has a url or not?
and how can i make the bot resends the original embed with all it's content regardless if it has a URL or not

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can easily check if the embed does not have a URL:

Just check if a key called "url" is in the `embed_content_in_dict` variable

```py
if 'url' in embed_content_in_dict.keys():
   #the embed has a url
   #do something
else:
  #the embed does not have a url
  #do something
```

For your second question:

You can use: `embed_content_in_dict.get('url')` instead of `embed_content_in_dict['url']`

If that embed does not have a url, `.get('url')` will return `None`

Comment: i seem to get this error **
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.url: Scheme "none" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').**

Comment: Oh, well that is true `None` is not a valid URL for an embed. I don't know how to get around this, sorry

Comment: it's all good, it seems you're not technically wrong because the error is not an actual exception and only triggers in 1.7.1 but not 1.6 of discord.py, i'm planning on using the latest version tho so i'm still searching for a sulotion

Comment: Oh, Good Luck though!